# Disable an HTML element, but not a form element

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to disable an HTML element with jQuery that it's not a form element?

For example:

```
<ul class="selectors">
  <li class="clear-selected">Clear Selected<span>&nbsp;</span></li>
  <li class="select-all">Select All<span>&nbsp;</span></li>
</ul>
```

Can I 'disable' the LI "clear-selected"?

What I'm trying to do is so that that LI can't be clicked on.

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
$('#x').attr('disabled', true);
```

http://docs.jquery.com/FAQ#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F

Thanks,

**EDIT--**

This question is part of a bigger case, here's the [**Main Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762777/buttons-activate-deactivate-elements-in-list-complex-case).

Thanks to everyone that answered.

Comment: What do you mean "can't be clicked on"?  Do you mean "make it so event handlers aren't triggered"?

Comment: li isn't a form element. It's an unordered list, so the example you link to doesn't make sense. Exactly what are you trying to do? You don't have a link in your code, so you must have a click function elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is part of a more complex case, here's the link to that solution: [Buttons activate/deactivate elements in list (complex case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762777/buttons-activate-deactivate-elements-in-list-complex-case)

Here's the jsfiddle [DEMO](http://www.jsfiddle.net/lmcculley/ujuH6/16/), notice how the "Clear Selected" button has no click action. It's 'faded' using opacity to convey the idea of 'inactive'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, by default nothing happens if you click on an li-element. I guess, you have click-handlers attached to your elements, that perform the described actions. In this case, you could just [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) these handlers to "disable" the elements.

Comment: +1 - Unbind would be the way I'd go with this as well, rather than adding an additional handler that returns false or prevents default.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. See my edit above. Yes, seems like unbind could definitely work for what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is disable the event handler for the element, you can do that like this:

```
$(".clear-selected").click(function() {
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either of these:

```
$(".clear-selected").hide();
$(".clear-selected").remove();
```

Edit: I think I read your question wrong.

What happens when they click the `li`? Can't really help you make the event stop if we don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "so that LI can't be clicked on", what do you mean by that? Do you have an onclick handler on that element? If so, you can simply remove the handler.