# Buttons activate/deactivate elements in list (complex case)

Tags: jquery

I've been trying as hard as I can but I think I'm over my head on this one, I just don't have the jQuery knowledge to accomplish what I need, I'm pretty new as you will see.

This may be a complex case, so I will try to explain as good as I can:

I have a list of items, LIs, grouped by titles in an accordion, so when you expand/collapse a section, you see the corresponding list for that section.

Each section contains the list and at the bottom of the list are two buttons: **Clear Selected** and **Select All**.

Upon entering the page, the first accordion section is expanded, inside you'll see the list, and at the bottom of the list you see the Clear Selected and Select All buttons. The Clear Selected button is visible but 'inactive'. To create the 'inactive' effect I just used *opacity:.5;* in the CSS. I need this button visible when it's 'inactive',

So far, I've been able to have the "Select All" button change its class, but the rest of the cases and behaviors are too complex for me.

The interaction between the buttons and the elements on the list, and between the buttons themselves is what I need help with.

Just FYI, what I'm building is a results system in which you can filter those results by clicking on the elements/options inside the accordions.

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ujuH6/8/).

Any help on this it's greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

**EDIT--**

Read the comments in the JavaScript section of the [**DEMO**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ujuH6/8/) to know the functionalities that are needed.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the 'select all' button is pressed? A class to be added to the nearby list-elements?

Comment: Yes, a class added. And I have already created this class, it's named ".active". As you can see in the comments in the demo, what I need is that when the 'Select All' button is pressed the first time, then all the elements in that list get the class ".active" added, and if they press it again, then have the class removed. Keep in mind that sometimes elements in the list could be already selected, so if the user clicks the 'Select All' button, then the remaining elements get selected. Does that make sense?

Comment: I can't help you **technically** because it's over my head, I've upvoted because  I think the question is very well put, but, for your own sake, I would recommend you to break down the problem into bits a little more since it may be too broad for a complete answer (I may be wrong) but that is the impression it left me. Good luck!

Comment: Trufa, yes, it is quite broad but that's why I came to stackoverflow.com, because I know there are awesome jQuery gurus here that you can learn from with every question. Lance, right below, is 99% close to the final solution I need for this, he's been a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have most of you're asking for worked out. Take a look at my code and see if it's what you're wanting.
http://www.jsfiddle.net/lmcculley/ujuH6/10/
Hope it works!

Comment: @Lance Select one item and click "select all" will inverse your selection. Is that a bug or correct?

Comment: I was under the impression with the comments from his jsfiddle that he wanted that as a feature.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late response. Your solutions work great Lance, however, the "Select All" inverting the selection is not what I want, what I need is to 'add' those unselected items and keep the ones already selected, selected. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ahhh, I understand what function you're wanting now. I've updated my jsfiddle to reflect the feature you're wanting. Take a look at the select-all click event to see my changes. I'll also update my answer with the new jsfiddle link. http://www.jsfiddle.net/lmcculley/ujuH6/10/

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I need Lance :). There's another issue I'm having now though with the Instructions and Results on the right side of the accordions. Depending on the selections on the left, either the Instructions or Results should be shown. I added another function below the 'else' of the Select All button, but it's not working really well. I updated the 'How To:' list. Here's the DEMO: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ujuH6/13/. I'm definitely buying you a beer Lance for your help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Would love it if you bought me Guinness, and accepted my answer. ;-)
Here's the new jsfiddle
http://www.jsfiddle.net/lmcculley/ujuH6/14/

Comment: Will do and that's a promise :) . However, there's a bug Lance :( - As you see, there are two accordion sections, if you click the 'Clear All' button from one section and you still have elements selected in the other one, the Instructions are shown. The Instructions should only be visible if no element from any section is selected whatsoever, and the Results should appear when at least one element from any section is selected. Thanks a lot for your time and patience. I updated the DEMO: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ujuH6/15/

Comment: Also, I changed the .show() and .hide() for .fadeIn(0)/fadeOut(0) to avoid the scaling animation. Not sure if that's the best/proper solution, but it seems to work fine.

Comment: Ok, so I don't mean to be rude, but I believe I've spent enough time on your solution. Here's your bugfix, but I would suggest that you look into how I accomplished the fix, and understand why it works that way instead of continuing this back and forth.
http://www.jsfiddle.net/lmcculley/ujuH6/16/

Comment: You are not being rude, I totally understand, and your solution works marvelously. I am serious about the beer, do you have a PayPal account? Or how do you want me to send your Guinness? Thanks a lot for your help and your time.

Comment: Sure do have PayPal, sir. lancemcculley[at]gmail[dot]com is the email address tied to my paypal. Thank you for the beer! :-D

Comment: Enjoy your BOX of Guinness beer amigo :). Thanks again.